# Cannot "fetch as Google" in Search Console after implementing HTTPS because of redirect

Tags: google-search-console, 301-redirect, https, fetch-as-google

We have recently switched from HTTP to HTTPS.  When I tried to "fetch as Google", it says the URL has been redirected and I am not able to see how the website is going to look.

Is it because Google Search Console was setup for `http://example.com` not for `https://example.com`?

If this is the issue then do I need to add a second property to Google Search Console for the domain with HTTPS?  What do I do with old authorization meta tag?

Comment: I always add four properties for every website: `http://`, `https://`, `http://www`, and `https://www`  they end up showing different data.

Comment: What URL're you're testing? HTTP or HTTPS? It says redirection, so is there any actual redirection?, please add more info.

Comment: I think I should have done more research before posting this question. Anyways, Thanks to all good people here. 

I have found the answer somewhere else and found out that google treats HTTPS;// as new property so I need to add this version as new property to WMT and then try to fetch as google. I hope that should solve the issue.